# Creating a bootstrap HTML/CSS box within a box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create HTML/CSS with the image below [![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am having trouble creating the silver "Add corkscrew" box with a white box below it and then finally another silver box within it. Any ideas how I can do that?

This is my code below but it looks nothing like the above image:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-right">

          <div class="row">
              <h2><font color="black">CorkBoard</font></h2>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <form action="/add-corkboard" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <!-- Email -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="emailid" class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="font-weight: normal">Title</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailid" name="emailid" placeholder="Enter your email account">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Dropdown
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="action">Home & Garden</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="another action">Education</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here">People</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="separated link">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}





    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rows can only contain columns, but you have the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <h2><font color="black">CorkBoard</font></h2>
</div>

You need to add a column in the row, something what like you did below that:

<div class="row row-content">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h2><font color="black">CorkBoard</font></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

You also need to wrap your dropdown class in rows and cols too.

Answer (score 0):

This may help get you going.
Highly suggest moving the inline styles to their own classes regardless of sample.

Thought not my preferred way, this is the bootstrap mostly way.
I did change container to container-fluid on all of them, seems to also fix another issue I noticed with responsive

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:silver">
    <div>
      <h6>Add CorkBoard</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:white">
      <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <br />
          <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:silver">
            <div class="row row-content">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-right">

                <div class="row row-content">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                    <h2>
                      <font color="black">CorkBoard</font>
                    </h2>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="row row-content" style="padding:15px">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                  <form action="/add-corkboard" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <!-- Email -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="emailid" class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="font-weight: normal">Title</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailid" name="emailid" placeholder="Enter your email account">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        Dropdown
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li><a href="#" data-value="action">Home & Garden</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-value="another action">Education</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here">People</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-value="separated link">Separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>

                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-content">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-content">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

However with a little bit of custom CSS you can achieve something slightly nicer, and improve on it and/or change it per your liking much easier.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
    .box {
      background-color: silver;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    .boxinabox {
      background-color: white;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 2.5%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid box">
    <h6>Add CorkBoard</h6>
    <div class="boxinabox">
      <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:silver">
        <div class="row row-content">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-right">

            <div class="row row-content">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <h2>
                  <font color="black">CorkBoard</font>
                </h2>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="row row-content" style="padding:15px">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
              <form action="/add-corkboard" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <!-- Email -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="emailid" class="col-sm-3 control-label" style="font-weight: normal">Title</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailid" name="emailid" placeholder="Enter your email account">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Dropdown
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="action">Home & Garden</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="another action">Education</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here">People</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="separated link">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm unsure if this is what you were asking about, sorry if I've gone off-topic. Please let me know if I did.